# How do you gzip multiple files using 7Zip from a context menu shortcut?

Tags: windows-7, windows, 7-zip

I have a bunch of files I'd like to individually zip up with a single action using 7Zip.

1) select all files
2) right click > 7-Zip > GZip
3) each file get's archived as .gz or or .zip

Effectively, I want it to act like the gzip function in unix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe` command line executable.  For usage instructions, run it without any parameters.

NOTE: The 7-Zip GUI launched from the Start Menu is `7zFM.exe`.  The 7-Zip GUI launched from the "7-Zip, Add to archive..." menu us `7zG.exe`.